# Python Django not able to get the data in a table form in my page instead it is returning a plain json object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Product</h1>
        <table id="products" border="1">
            <thead>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="product-id"></td>
                    <td id="product-Name"></td>
                    <td id="product-quantity"></td>
                    <td id="product-price"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        <a href="{% url 'index' %}"><button id="back-button">Back</button></a>
    </div>
    <script>
        fetchProductDetails();
    
        function fetchProductDetails() {
            const productId = getProductIdFromUrl();
            fetch(`/product/${productId}`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    const productData = data;
                    const productTable = document.getElementById('productId');
                    const tbody = productTable.querySelector('tbody');
                    const row = document.createElement('tr');
                    row.innerHTML = `
                        <td>${productData.id}</td>
                        <td>${productData.Name}</td>
                        <td>${productData.quantity}</td>
                        <td>${productData.price}</td>
                    `;
                    tbody.appendChild(row);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
        }
    
        function getProductIdFromUrl() {
            const urlSegments = window.location.href.split('/');
            return urlSegments[urlSegments.length - 2]; 
        }
    </script>
    
    
</body>
```

and my urls.py line which redirects me to the method

```
path('product/<int:id>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

and corresponding views method from the urls.py

```
def product_detail(request, id):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=id, user=request.user)
        product_data = {
            'id': product.id,
            'Name': product.Name,
            'quantity': product.quantity,
            'price': product.price
        }
        return JsonResponse(product_data)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

and my urls.py

```
path('product/<int:id>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

I am getting the response like this when i hit
http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/9/

[image]

I am not able to render my getbyid.html page, any suggestions?

I am expecting a table defined in getbyid.html and the json values to be populated in that table

I got it without using fetch which is in tabluar form as well but I want to use fetch as i want to call restapi from front end

my view method without rest-

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def product_detail(request, id):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
        return render(request, 'getbyid.html', {'product': product})
```

and my body in getbyid.html

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Product</h1>
        <table id="products" border="1">
            <thead>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>{{product.id}}</td>
                <td>{{product.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{product.price}}</td>
                <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        <a href="{% url 'index' %}"><button id="new3">Back</button></a>
    </div>
```

this is giving me expected outcome which is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two approaches:

a) render hmtl template with context directly at "url_a"

b) render html template at "url_a" and add data dynamically by js fetch call to "url_b"

in your example (a) works but then going to structure (b) you change url_a to return JSON data that in fact should come from "url_b"

So the solution could be to keep the original view and add another view/path url_b to get JSON data like:

urls.py

```
path('product/<int:id>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
path('fetch_product/<int:id>/', views.fetch_product_detail, name='fetch_product_detail'),
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def fetch_product_detail(request, id):
    try:
         ....
        return JsonResponse(product_data)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def product_detail(request, id):
        return render(request, 'getbyid.html', {'productId': id})
```

Another hint:
in order to define routings only in urls.py once, it is more django style to define the fetch url via the path name:

```
function fetchProductDetails() {
   const productId = getProductIdFromUrl();
   fetch(`/product/${productId}`)

change to

function fetchProductDetails() {
   fetch(`{% url "fetch_product_detail" productId %}`)
```